# What is the efficient sound configuration for CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[In this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tibib9xD7qg), this guy's game sound is very sensitive. He can easily hear burning car's sound while he was passing near. So is there and config to do so, like some console commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this entries to Your config autoexec.cfg:

`dsp_enhance_stereo "1"`

`dsp_slow_cpu "0"`

`dsp_reload`

> "dsp_enhance_stereo [0,1] - If set to 1 enhances the stereo effect, making sound richer and more atmospheric for a slight performance hit."
>
> "dsp_slow_cpu [0,1] - If set to 1, reduces the quality of dsp sound effects, improving performance on systems with slower CPUs."

Comment: `dsp_slow_cpu 0` is the default value.

Comment: What is `dsp_reload` command?

Answer (score -1):

There may be a setting in the config/setting file/folder but your best bet is speaker configuration in the audio options menu and a nice set of speakers or headphones running surround sound. Hope this helps.